# Does Sachdev's Maxwell relation always hold?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics

In the paper [Bekenstein-Hawking Entropy and Strange Metals](https://arxiv.org/abs/1506.05111), the following Maxwell relation is given (equation 40)
$$\left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial Q}\right)_T = - \left(\frac{\partial \mu}{\partial T}\right)_Q\tag{40}$$
where $S$ is the entropy per particle, $Q$ is the fermionic number density $Q = \frac{1}{N}\sum _{i=1}^N\langle \hat{c}_i^\dagger \hat{c}_i\rangle$, $T$ is the temperature and $\mu$ is the chemical potential.

The [Maxwell relations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell_relations) in the Grand canonical ensemble, should be derivable from the differential $$d\Omega = - S dT - Q d \mu - p d V.$$

Given the Sachdev's identity however, it would imply the existence of some differential
$$dz = S dQ - \mu dT.$$

Which I cannot see as a general relation, so what am I missing? There is a chance that this relation only holds as one is taking $T\to 0$. Then, I would still like to know how one shows this in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the Legendre transform $G=\Omega+\mu Q$ then
$$dG=-SdT+\mu dQ-pdV$$
The first derivatives are
$$S=-\left({\partial G\over\partial T}\right)_{Q},\quad\quad
   \mu=\left({\partial G\over\partial Q}\right)_{T}$$
The equality
$${\partial^2G\over\partial T\partial Q}
   ={\partial^2G\over\partial Q\partial T}$$
leads to
$$-\left({\partial S\over\partial Q}\right)_{T}
   =\left({\partial \mu\over\partial T}\right)_{Q}$$
as expected.